# Can my new pressure switch's range be adjusted to match the original?

Tags: switch

I replaced my Pressure tank which had a leak. As I was putting the pluming back together I noticed the contacts in the 40/60 Square D switch.Can you use a 30/50 Square D pressure switch (a new on which I happen to have on hand) to replace a 40/60 pressure switch and raise the range to 40/60?

Comment: You might be able to get somewhat close, but my experience is you wont get the full 10 psi differential, the springs are different in the correct switch.

Comment: I frequent this forum and it seems that people frequently adjust their pressure switch up to 40/60 from 30/50 but you could ask: https://terrylove.com/forums/index.php?forums/pumps-and-tanks-well-forum-blog-water-is-life.4/

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the switch.

The particular one (it's also a Square D, but they make various models) I have on my well is a 20 PSI differential and can be adjusted from 20/40 to 40/60 (perhaps beyond, I don't recall right now.) Check the instructions (should be in the box if it's brand-new, or look up the exact model number on-line.)

Instructions for the 9013 Pumptrol show a larger nut (1) and a smaller nut (2) with the following instructions:

> Adjust in the proper sequence:
>   1. Range: Turn nut down (CW) for higher cut-in pressure, or up
>   (CCW) for lower cut-in.
>   2. Differential: Turn nut down (CW) for higher cut-out pressure, or up
>   (CCW) for lower cut-out.

I will warn to be sure that power to the circuit is off at any point when adjusting the nuts - with the cover off to access the nuts, the line power contacts are exposed, and I prefer the level of being careful that shuts that off at the breaker to the level of being careful that is "I should avoid touching those."

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Tyson. That company makes different switches for different pressures.  If they could be adjusted effectively across the range, why make two different switches.  They are made to accept minor adjustments only.