# can i change the differential to 10 psi on a well p/s to make it cut in at 10 psi and cut out at 20 psi

Tags: switch, well, pressure

I set my new pump at appt 190'in a appt. 200' hole,the mfg performance sheet said i should get 19 psi& 8.9 gpm. At 197'. at 190' I get appt. 21 psi & appt.10 gpm , I set my bladder tank at 8 psi,i can get it to turn on around 10 psi,but it will not shut off.I am have a 30-50 p/s, is there anyway I can make it work to cut in at 10 and out at 20. Thank You for any help You can give me

My switch is a home depot everbilt 30-50 psi

Comment: Depends on the pressure switch. And you haven't told us what brand and model that is.

Comment: If you happen to have the same pressure switch I do: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/129456/18078 Why did you pick a pump that can't even give 20 PSI? When buying a new pump, there are many choices - I get better than 60 PSI from 300 ft down and it was pretty much the same price as the ones that wouldn't do that...

Comment: Can you expand the abbreviation "appt" please?  Google only suggests "appointment".  Did you mean "approx" (for "approximately".

Comment: I bought that pump because of price ( $219 China & Amazon), I would love too find a pump in that price  range, like my old American made one,(1/2 hp franklin motor / 15 stage Mc Donald pump, appt. price $1074.+ tx & , freight ) If you could tell me what pump you got , That would very helpfull.    Thank You

Comment: The wrong pump "cheap" just makes the right pump more expensive after you have wasted money & time on buying, installing, and removing the wrong pump. I have an all-stainless Myers with Pentair motor, which is irrelevant to your current shopping issue since it's also bought 12 years ago, more or less. Perhaps you should rebuild your old pump.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be happy with it. Your showers etc will not do much more then dribble. Second floor will be almost nothing and expect the tolits to take maybe 15 minutes to refill. As indicated before get another pump and return this. If your pressure switch is like the one I use to have you can adjust both the pressure and the differential.

Comment: I have used the shower & it is ok,if you could tell what switch you found that I can adjust both pressure & differential. thank you

Comment: That would be switch dependent. I did that with our well many years ago and in another part of the country. You could probably look it up on the web. Here is a video that is similar to what I had. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwwMtVvKrXs Be sure to check your pressure gauge, 10 PSIG sounds very low to take a shower. I know how bad ours was with 20 PSIG.